# Get symmetric elements of a non-symmetric sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am having a non-symmetric (`csr`) matrix `A` and given the indexes of the non-zero elements, in the `i`-th row, `A[i].indices`, I want to obtain the corresponding elements in the `i`-th column `A[A[i].indices, :]`. However, as the matrix is not symmetric the returned elements are not of the same size as the `A[i].indices`. I suppose some indices in `A[i].indices` correspond to zero elements in the `i`-th column.
For example, with index starting from zero, in matrix `A` below, `A[0].indices=[1,2]` and `A[A[0].indices, :]=[a_{31}]`.

[image]

Is it possible to obtain **efficiently** all elements (including zeros) that correspond in `A[A[0].indices, :]`? That is, to obtain `A[A[0].indices, :] = [a_{21}, a_{31}]`, with `a_{21}=0`.

Thank you you advance.

Comment: Anything wrong with `A[A[idx].indices,idx].A`?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. Do you mean transpose? The matrix is not symmetric, it does not help.

Comment: What do you mean do I mean transpose? There is no transpose in that snippet. What it does is (1) extract the indices of nonzeros of the idx'th row (2) uses them to fancy-index into the idx'th column and (3) converts the resulting sparse matrix to dense.